# Deleting a row from my database, using AND keyword

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

So I want to delete a row from my listbox, and this is where the user presses delete and the program should do its thing. The only thing is that it doesnt. If I am just deleting the first name, it will work fine and my database updates, but when I try to do both first and last name, it doesn't work. Can someone please help me. I am new to this and this is for an assignment for school. Thank you very much.

Cheers

```
SqlConnection cn;
        cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data source=(local); Initial Catalog=INT422Assignment1;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE firstName=@firstName AND lastName=@lastName";


        SqlParameter param;
        param = new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = firstNameDelete.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = lastNameDelete.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();




        MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
        this.Close();
```

Comment: instead of reusing `param`, have you tried using different variable names?

Comment: I'll take one more stab before I quit flailing around: change the parameters to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstNameDelete.Text)`. Have you checked that only deleting by lastName works? Did you check that the values in firstNameDelete.Text and lastNameDelete.Text are what you want/expect?

Comment: Does a command text work with parameters like that? I've never seen it used that way before.

Comment: @Yatrix Yes it does, that's how we've done it in the past, we used the shortened parameter adding in the comment above though.

Comment: Learn something new every day. Think I'll stick to stored procedures, though. =)

Comment: @EssiJoon Are you getting an error of any kind or is it just doing nothing?

Comment: So it seems the problem is with the lastName, cause I just checked only last name and it ididnt work, but again I tried only first name and that worked. So something is messing up here!

Comment: You sure you're not including a space or anything in the textbox? I'd always use a Trim() if I was taking a textbox's text.

Comment: Spaces maybe? Capitalization? Try replacing = with LIKE.

Comment: I've tried Like, no Dice still... the problem seems to with the the lastName... cause when I did firstName alone it worked, but when I tried to do lastName alone, it didnt work.

Comment: @EssiJoon Is the column name right? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Have you tried running SQL profiler to see what statement is getting executed on the database side?

Comment: Any special characters in the family names? Diacritics? Accents?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the wrong approach from the start. Suppose you have two Johns, John Smith and John Doe. If your query is:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE FirstName="John";
```

That means all entries with "John" as their first name will be removed, both Johns.

If you have:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE FirstName="John" AND LastName="Doe";
```

Then in theory John Doe will be removed. Again, what if you have more than one John Doe? Do you want to remove them all?

What you want, if you want to remove a single entry, is to remove according to a hidden column in your list containing a unique ID, or better yet, to bind your listbox to your table.

Comment: His query uses both first and last.

Comment: MPelletier, Thank you very much for your response. So in this case, for the purpose of this introductory assignment, there wont be a long list of entries, 4 or 5. 

Essentially, since there is no unique ID (as per the instructions - thought that would have made life so much easier), the first name and the last name are a composite PK. 

I can't use bind my listbox to my table, i have to populate the data straight from the database. 

if I go on Microsoft SQL and write my query and execute it, it works fine. it is only within VS that it doesnt work.

Comment: @Yatrix: I know, I was just giving the asker an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using This Query and check Lower or upper Case Char

> DELETE FROM myTable WHERE Upper(FirstName)=Upper(@firstName) AND Upper(LastName)=Upper("@LastName");

or you can use Like not = if you not search for exactly words

and you can check row affected from execution

> int numberOfRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: The comparison is case insensitive, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Yatrix It depends on the COLLATION settings. Default is usually something CI (case insensitive) but ..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently "wrong" with that code. However (and mostly a recap of the comments):

1. Make sure the input values are as expected<sup>1</sup> and verify the command runs (with the expected values) in SSMS or similar interactive SQL client<sup>2</sup>.
2. Make sure the casing/spacing is correct. If this matters depends on the COLLATION setting for the particular column. Again, trying the command from SSMS or similar tool would show if this works or not.
3. Inspect the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` for the "number of records" altered. It should be 1 if the DELETE was successful. There could be something really fishy with transaction scopes going on, so this value is important to observe. Although this is unlikely if it "work[s] fine" with just the first name, this is a good check to perform.

---

<sup>1</sup> Use the Visual Studio debugger to inspect the values at the time they are bound to the parameters.

<sup>2</sup> Transactions can be used to avoid "really deleting" during these tests. Alternatively, `DELETE` can be altered to `SELECT` as it will have no impact on the actual query (`WHERE .. AND`) logic.

Comment: it isn't a textbox, it is a label and I am grabbing the label of the textbox and using that in my statement.

Comment: @EssiJoon Same idea: verify the values - e.g. in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry guys for the late response. So essentially this is what I did wrong : in my main form, when I was populating my listbox, this is what I used:

```
s = reader["firstName"].ToString() + "-" + reader["lastName"].ToString(); studentInfoListBox.Items.Add(s); }
```

and in the deleteItem form, I did the following:

```
string[] b = curItem.Split('-'); firstNameDelete.Text = b[0].ToString(); lastNameDelete.Text = b[1].ToString();
```

So I had put in an extra space in the main form part " - "